# Python Regex Substitution - is a conditional replace possible?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will ensure a 'tag' is properly re-formatted in accordance with a specification.  (I'm updating a bunch of legacy stuff.)

The general idea is that a tag can have bracketed content in either `()` or `[]`.  However the existing tags might be malformed:

- good :

  - `Sample (sample)`
  - `Sample [sample]`
- bad :

  - `Sample (( sample  )`
  - `Sample [(sample]]`

I am currently handling this in a series of regex, but I'm wondering if it's technically possible to do it in a single one.

In a simplified version of the code...

```
RE_tag_collapse = re.compile(\
    """
        ([\[\(])+               ### opening bracket
            \s*
            (                   # the contents
                [^\]\)]+
            )
            \s*
        ([\]\)])*               # closing bracket
    """
    ,
    re.I | re.VERBOSE
)
edited= re.sub( RE_tag_collapse , r'\1\2\1' , tag )
```

The problem with this regex is that the closing tag (the second `\1`) is the same as the opening tag.

What I'd want to do is map the closing tag to be the inverse of the opening tag:

- `(` inverts to `)`
- `[` inverts to `]`

Does anyone know if this is easily feasible?   It looks to me like my best solution is to leave things as-is and use multiple regexes.

Comment: for a single pair it's easy, you can just use a back-reference: `([\[\(]).*\1`, for more than that, i'm obligated to tell you not to use a regex because matching bracket pairs is not "regular" or something like that.

Comment: the fact that it's not "regular" means that you wouldn't be able to check it with a finite state machine (fsm), because that would require an infinite ammount of states, since the number of brackets can be infinitely big.

Comment: If Python's PCRE engine is compatible with Perl 5.10, recursive patterns should be supported, and this can be used to match balanced expressions. See the section RECURSIVE PATTERNS at http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

Comment: thanks mark.  i've got the back reference in there already.  you're right about it not being regular - i've got a function handling the full tag migration; I was really wondering if i could make an 'irregular expression' match.

Comment: @Mark: Your solution wouldn't even work because `([\[\(]).*\1` would match `[foo[` but not `[foo]`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Very true. I do this often for matching single *or* double-quotes, but I clearly didn't think this through for the case of brackets ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to make sure that the parenthesis in your tags match. As far as I know, regexes in python have no way to count occurences. However, you could use a function to check if the parenthesis match like this:

```
def check_tag(tag):
    charstack = []
    for c in tag:
        if c in ["(","]"]:
            charstack.append(c)
        else if c in [")","]"]:
            popped = charstack.pop()
            if not ((c == ")" and popped == "(" ) or (c == "]" and popped == "[")):
                return False
    return len(charstack) == 0
```

The way this function works, is every time it finds an opening parenthesis, it pushes it onto a stack. Every time it encounters a closing parenthesis, it pushes an element off the stack to see if they match. If they don't, than the tag is improperly formatted.

Comment: Great answer. What about setting a tuple of strings `correct = ('()', '[]')` and checking `if not ''.join([popped, c]) in correct: return False` instead?

Comment: that would indeed make it more flexible, so that if you'd like to add stuff like { and } or < and >, you'd only have to edit that tuple instead of editing strings all over the code, and making that if statement even more complex.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your regexp to capture all the opening and closing brackets as groups, then you can generate the correct closing bracket set from the opening bracket set and use that in the regexp substitution

Like this:

```
>>> def subber(matchobj):
    return ' '.join([matchobj.group(1),
             matchobj.group(2),
             matchobj.group(1).replace('[',']').replace('(', ')')[::-1]])

>>> new_RE = re.compile(\
    """
        ([\[\(]+)               ### opening brackets
            \s*
            (                   # the contents
                [^\]\)]+
            )
            \s*
        ([\]\)]+)               # closing brackets
    """
    ,
    re.I | re.VERBOSE
)
>>> txt = 'Sample [(sample]]'
>>> new_RE.sub(subber, txt)
'Sample [( sample )]'
>>>
```

The closing brackets are just substituting every open bracket for its closing one in the group capturing the opening brackets then reversing it.